# How can I find the root cause for class not found issue, in OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, equinox, osgi-bundle

I want to try some steps to fix ClassNotFound issue. Im using Equinox/OSGI.
For example, im getting

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
```

I tried, ss, ls -c, diag , b commands..but could not find any useful info from that. I put the output of those commands..

Can anybody let me know, how can i go through such OSgi issues and how can i figure out the root cause for such issues..

```
#osgi> p org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet
org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.2.0 [421]>

#osgi> diag 421
reference:file:../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.2.0.jar [421]
  No unresolved constraints.

#osgi> b 421
org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.2.0 [421]
  Id=421, Status=ACTIVE      Data Root=C:\Projects\scartch\chunk13\08_07_new\wso2am-1.7.1\repository\components\default\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi
\bundles\421\data
  "No registered services."
  Services in use:
    {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService, org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserRealmService}={service.id=136}
    {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.api.CarbonTomcatService}={service.id=130}
    {org.wso2.carbon.base.api.ServerConfigurationService}={service.id=103}
    {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service.RegistryService, org.wso2.carbon.registry.api.RegistryService}={service.id=143}
  Exported packages
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.scan; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.saas; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.utils; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.realms; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.transport; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet; version="4.2.0"[exported]
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.transport.statistics; version="4.2.0"[exported]
  Imported packages
    org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.utils_4.2.0 [454]>
    org.wso2.carbon.utils; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.utils_4.2.0 [454]>
    org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.2.0 [449]>
    org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.2.0 [449]>
    org.wso2.carbon.user.api; version="1.0.1"<org.wso2.carbon.user.api_4.2.0 [448]>
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.api; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.2.0 [420]>
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.2.0 [420]>
    org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service; version="1.0.1"<org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.2.0 [344]>
    org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.ghostregistry; version="1.0.1"<org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.2.0 [344]>
    org.wso2.carbon.registry.api; version="1.0.1"<org.wso2.carbon.registry.api_4.2.0 [341]>
    org.wso2.carbon.core.session; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.core_4.2.0 [197]>
    org.wso2.carbon.core; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.core_4.2.0 [197]>
    org.wso2.carbon.context; version="4.2.0"<org.wso2.carbon.utils_4.2.0 [454]>
    org.wso2.carbon.base.api; version="1.0.0"<org.wso2.carbon.base_4.2.0 [189]>
    org.wso2.carbon.base; version="1.0.0"<org.wso2.carbon.base_4.2.0 [189]>
    org.osgi.service.component; version="1.2.0"<org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822 [132]>
    org.eclipse.osgi.framework.adaptor; version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521 [0]>
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet; version="1.1.0"<org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120522-1841 [102]>
    org.apache.tomcat.util.scan; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.tomcat.util.res; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.tomcat.util.file; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.tomcat; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.juli.logging; version="7.0.34"<tribes_7.0.34.wso2v1 [496]>
    org.apache.coyote; version="1.7.0"<org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.patch_4.2.0 [423]>
    org.apache.commons.logging; version="1.1.1"<org.wso2.carbon.logging_4.2.0 [287]>
    org.apache.catalina.valves; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.catalina.startup; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.catalina.realm; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.catalina.ha; version="1.7.0"<tomcat-ha_7.0.34.wso2v1 [495]>
    org.apache.catalina.core; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.catalina.connector; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.catalina; version="1.7.0"<tomcat_7.0.34.wso2v1 [494]>
    org.apache.axis2.clustering; version="1.6.1.wso2v10"<axis2_1.6.1.wso2v10 [13]>
    javax.servlet.http; version="2.6.0"<javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016 [57]>
    javax.servlet; version="2.6.0"<javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016 [57]>
  No fragment bundles
  Named class space
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext; bundle-version="4.2.0"[provided]
  No required bundles


#osgi> ls -c 421
Components in bundle org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext:
ID      Component details
139     Component[
        name = tomcat.ext.service.comp
        factory = null
        autoenable = true
        immediate = true
        implementation = org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.CarbonRealmServiceComponent
        state = Unsatisfied
        properties = {service.pid=tomcat.ext.service.comp}
        serviceFactory = false
        serviceInterface = null
        references = {
                Reference[name = user.realm.provider, interface = org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 1..1
, target = null, bind = setRealmService, unbind = unsetRealmService]
                Reference[name = registry.service.provider, interface = org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service.RegistryService, policy = dynamic, cardi
nality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setRegistryService, unbind = unsetRegistryService]
        }
        located in bundle = org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.2.0 [421]
]
Dynamic information :
  The component is satisfied
  All component references are satisfied
  Component configurations :
    Configuration properties:
      service.pid = tomcat.ext.service.comp
      component.name = tomcat.ext.service.comp
      component.id = 138
    Instances:
      org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.impl.ComponentInstanceImpl@68c19d85
        Bound References:
        String[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service.RegistryService,org.wso2.carbon.registry.api.RegistryService]
                -> org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService@7f4cbc7d
        String[org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService,org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserRealmService]
                -> org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService@6eaf3d6

140     Component[
        name = tomcat.service.comp
        factory = null
        autoenable = true
        immediate = true
        implementation = org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.CarbonTomcatServiceComponent
        state = Unsatisfied
        properties = {service.pid=tomcat.service.comp}
        serviceFactory = false
        serviceInterface = null
        references = {
                Reference[name = server.configuration.service, interface = org.wso2.carbon.base.api.ServerConfigurationService, policy = dynamic, card
inality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setServerConfigurationService, unbind = unsetServerConfigurationService]
                Reference[name = tomcat.service.provider, interface = org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.api.CarbonTomcatService, policy = dynamic, cardinality =
1..1, target = null, bind = setCarbonTomcatService, unbind = unsetCarbonTomcatService]
        }
        located in bundle = org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.2.0 [421]
]
Dynamic information :
  The component is satisfied
  All component references are satisfied
  Component configurations :
    Configuration properties:
      service.pid = tomcat.service.comp
      component.name = tomcat.service.comp
      component.id = 139
    Instances:
      org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.impl.ComponentInstanceImpl@2b2e6a26
        Bound References:
        String[org.wso2.carbon.base.api.ServerConfigurationService]
                -> org.wso2.carbon.base.ServerConfiguration@4c309c86
        String[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.api.CarbonTomcatService]
                -> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat@b74487e
```

Answer (score 1):

You diagnosed the plugin providing the class. Looking at the requester might help as well.

In general troubleshooting OSGi class loading is hard. Incompatible libraries versions and duplicated libraries are the most popular causes of ClassNotFoundException. So, looking for config changes around the time of the crash might give you some hints.

Is the stack trace complete? If no you can paste the whole stack, might help.